# How to calculate frequency band of a dipole antennae

Tags: antenna, dipole

I'm a bit puzzled on why dipole antennas can be used in FM receivers. Given that dipole antennae is just tuned to one particular frequency which can be derived from it's length using \$\frac{c}{2L}\$ then how it is capable of receiving variable frequency signal without any problems? This made me believe that signal strength loss does not deteriorate until the difference between transmitted frequency and frequency the dipole is tuned to exceeds some value. I'm trying to understand if this is the case? And if it is why is this the case?
Finally, I want to know how can i compute the frequency range for individual dipole in which signal strength is acceptable for further use?

Comment: Yes, dipoles have a bandwidth.

Comment: For *horizontal* dipoles, height above ground affects gain toward a distant transmitter, especially where height-above-ground exceeds about half-wavelength. If the transmitter is a terrestrial source, you generally want a receiving dipole many wavelengths above ground. Not so for a low-earth-orbit satellite transmitter where a receiving dipole height of about 1/3 wavelength is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common metric for dipole bandwidth is where the band-edge frequencies have a SWR = 2:1. Dipole bandwidth is influenced by conductor diameter where larger diameter gives wider bandwidth. For the FM broadcast band in the U.S., 88 to 108 MHz, the bandwidth for an antenna to cover that range is 20 MHz, or about 20% of the center frequency. Practical dipoles can get around 10% bandwidth at VHF frequencies using AWG 10 to 14 gauge wire using the NEC antenna models.

To increase bandwidth, you can play games with the antenna design. Placing "hats" on the end is a common trick. 
Using folded dipoles is another method which is a common antenna configuration for 300 ohm feed-point antennas which just happens to be a popular antenna configuration for FM broadcast receivers. It was hard to find out how much increase in bandwidth the folded dipole offers over a simple dipole, but one [source](https://www.w8ji.com/folded_dipole.htm) suggested about 1.5x times increase with his simulations showing the bandwidth tracked closely with wire diameter (folded dipole has larger wire diameter due to the two conductors). Thus, you might expect 15% bandwidth for the folded dipole which covers most of the bandwidth of the frequency range. Just expect poorer efficiency at the fringes of the band.

You'll find that using a random piece of wire will work as an antenna if the signal strength is strong enough. If you're in a fringe area, antenna design and placement can be critical.

Comment: Yes, I was indeed more curious about a wire toy example as I'm basically trying to make an FM receiver from the ground up. I'm starting with an antennae and I was curious how do I know how far from the resonant frequency in both directions the signal would remain strong.